# selecting where in multiple columns on ANSI SQL (IMPALA SQL)

Tags: python, sql, where-clause, impala, ansi-sql

It worked normally in Oracle SQL, but it does not work in ANSI SQL.

```
SELECT whatever WHERE (col1,col2) IN ((val1, val2), (val1, val2), ...)
```

How do I write code in ANSI SQL (IMPALA SQL)?

I don't want the following code because there are many lists.

```
WHERE (col1 = val1a AND col2 = val2a)
   OR (col1 = val1b AND col2 = val2b)
   ...
```

thank you!

(ex)
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34266/selecting-where-two-columns-are-in-a-set

We can do smooth operation in ANSI sql.

Comment: The Oracle way is ANSI SQL compliant (using optional features F641, Row and table constructors, T051, Row types and F561, Full value expressions.) Verified by https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/.

Comment: Either stick with your current workaround, or put the values in a (temporary) table and JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

This isnt possible in hive or impala. Only 'other' workaround is concat().
You can use below sql-

```
...
where concat(col1,'~',col2) IN (concat(val1,'~',val2),concat(val3,'~',val4)...)
```

Pls note if col1/col2 is null, it wont be matched.

EDIT : this can have severe performance problem. So, you can store val1,val2 in a static/lookup table and then use it to join with main table like this -

```
select ...
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.col1=t2.val1 and t1.col2=t2.val2
```

You also have flexibility to change values as per future need and not change the sql.

Comment: But it takes a long time...

Comment: Any type of tuple concat with `or` will take time. I would concat them and  put values in a table and compare - faster than concat and in clause.

Comment: Note that `concat('ab', 'c') = concat('a', 'bc')`, but `('ab', 'c') <> ('a', 'bc')`. Also, risky trick like this makes the query harder to optimize, which leads to poor performance.

Comment: Thtats a very good point, so i am changing the answer and added a delimiter.

Comment: Pls can you check alaternate solution... Much faster than concat.